# Se ha producido un error interno en el servidor Id. del error: 1030073819-48846 (1817289769)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

Al usuario le sale rara vez, un mensaje de error cuando usa un componente aura. "Se ha producido un error interno en el servidor Id. del error: 1030073819-48846 (1817289769) "o"  Id. del error: 583947032-104585(1817289769)"

Comment: Bienvenidos a SFSE. La idioma de esta sitio es Ingles. Puede traducir su puesto? Gracias.

Comment: Y tambien, debe contactar con Salesforce Support, porque no podemos assistarte con "gacks" (error interno en el servidor).

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta

Comment: Según los registros internos de Salesforce, el Id. de stacktrace 1817289769 apunta a java.lang.NullPointerException. (Translated using Google translate)